# MySQL Update if field contains certain characters

Tags: mysql

Im trying to update a field only if the field contains certain characters j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r
I want to avoid using `update tbl set field = field2 where field like '%j'` or `field like '%k'` ...etc.

Is there some syntax to create a list of the characters I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in MySQL:

`update tbl set field = field2 where field REGEXP 'j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r';`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions with the RegExp keywork.

Comment: I tried writing this staement but iget an error that repetition-operator operand invalid from regexp    , im trying to see if the field has any of the characters from j-r in the end of the field UPDATE FIELD SET FIELD = FIELD2 WHERE FIELD RLIKE '*[J-R]'

Comment: I think you mean `'^[J-R]'` not `'*[J-R]'`

Comment: ok actually i had to write it out like this RLIKE 'j|k|l|m|n|o|p|q|r'

Comment: what if in turn I also need to replace any of those characters with a 0 how would i write that replace statement without writing replace a million times  i tried this but it wont work REPLACE(`NON COVERED PLAN PAID AMOUNT (NPP)`,'*[J-R]','0')

Comment: Yes it wont work because MySQL looks for a string `*[J-R]` not for a regular expression, it can't find it, so nothing happens.

Comment: Take a look at this link, it may help : https://github.com/hholzgra/mysql-udf-regexp